# Using Amazon S3 to Host Flash Videos... Why does the FlashVar show no file extension?

Tags: flash, amazon-s3, flowplayer

I'm using FlowPlayer to replace an existing FLV player on my site that plays videos from Amazon E3.

I have many pages and each should show a different video.

For each page, I have a value stored in my CMS that is the "streamName".

The stream name corresponds to a flashvars paramenter in the object/embed tags that show the video player:

```
&streamName=my-great-video
```

On my new player, I'm able to get the video using a URL similar to

```
https://mygreatsite.s3.amazonaws.com/my-great-video.swf?{$authentication_params}
```

**How Does Flash (or Amazon???) know to add in the .swf extension?**

There are several video formats used on the site, and the current player works with them all...
But, as I mentioned above, on each page the value store for the video (ex="my-great-video") includes no extension.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your problem but shouldn't your CMS templates contain code that build the right url based on your streamName variable?
And, by the way, I guess you refer to Amazon S3, not E3, don't you?

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo... I had E3 in the title, should be S3.... E3 sounds more fun :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's working without supplied extension then a wild guess is: whatever is parsing the querystring has logic to attempt the GET using an assortment of supported extensions [swf, flv, mp3] if one isn't seen?

Comment: You must be right, but since I don't have the FLA I can't tell for sure. I ended up using only flv videos... and using PHP to detect weather or not "path_to_videos" + "streamname" + ".flv" exists.